# SELECT values of a column that are not in another column in the same table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a sample table called "Quant1" as follows (ID - int PK, Name - Varchar(45), Salary - float, manager_id - int):

| ID | Name | Salary | Manager_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 300 | 3 |
| 2 | Mike | 200 | 3 |
| 3 | Sally | 550 | 4 |
| 4 | Jane | 500 | 7 |
| 5 | Joe | 600 | 7 |
| 6 | Dan | 600 | 3 |
| 7 | Phil | 550 | NULL |

I want to list employees not managing anyone, i.e. ID 1,2,5,6.So I write the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM quant1
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT manager_id
    FROM quant1);
```

But it doesn't result in the desired outcome. Can anyone spot the error in my script? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the current output from your query?

Comment: From the query above it shows nothing. When I only SELECT id then it results in NULL value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to exclude the `NULL` manager ID from the subquery, because all comparisons with `NULL` fail.

```
SELECT *
FROM quant1
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT manager_id
    FROM quant1
    WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL);
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc7ca1/5)

Answer (score 0):

This query will return all rows from the table_name table where the column_name column is not contained in the column_name column from the table_name table.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name NOT IN (SELECT column_name FROM table_name)
```

Comment: That's the format of the query in the question. How does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM quant1
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT manager_id
    FROM quant1 WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL);
```